# Value not in query result

Tags: database, ms-access, criteria

OK, third time attempting to write this.
Essentially I need to make a query that can check through a table and insure that a value in each record does NOT equal a value in a record from a query

Overview

Query 1 searches through Bookings
where: Start Date < ['End Date'] AND End Date > ['Start Date']
displaying the BID (Booking ID) and VID (vehicle ID)

Query 2 searches through Bookings again but removes all records that have the same VID as the results in query 1

the problem is occurring where in query 2, if more that 1 result is displayed in Query 1, then it just displays the whole bookings table.

I currently use:

```
Field:    VID
Table:    Bookings
Criteria: <>[Query1].[VID]
```

i have been trying to figure this method out for the last 2 months now and still haven't got any further. any method i try of completing the task only works in certain cases.

essentially i am trying to create a query to see if a vehicle is available for rental for a specific date range.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be useful to see your tables. I assume that your Bookings table shows when vehicles have been booked for rental? So do you have a separate table of Vehicles? If so, then to see what vehicles are available for rental for a given date range, what you really need is to select entries from the Vehicles table where the VID is not in [Query 1]. This would be written as:

```
select * from Vehicles where VID Not In (select VID from Query1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to turn these things into a Rube Goldberg machine if you're not careful.  It sounds to me like this is a process you use to ensure proper data integrity in your database?  If that is the case, I would recommend automating that process by a few different methods:

- If using SQL backend, set a conditional statement for the VID field
- If the table is in Access, use the Validation Rule under the
  properties section for the desired field
- Or alternatively, have a composite key set for the two fields.